# Trying to run an IF statement inside a FOR loop in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a new column in my dataset and populate it with text based on a value in another column. The data does not only containt ST. There are other positions but just this is the one I am testing with.

I have being trying to do this by using an IF statement inside an FOR loop

**Current Data (There is not only one person, this is just the player I am testing with)**

```
short_name    team_position    position_group
J. Obika          ST                NA
D. Payet          LW                NA
D. Luiz           CB                NA
```

**Below is how I want the data to look**

```
short_name    team_position    position_group
J. Obika          ST              FORWARD
D. Payet          LW              FORWARD
D. Luiz           CB              DEFENDER
```

**Below is some code I tried**

```
for(i in 1:length(fifa20datasample$team_position)){
  if(fifa20datasample$team_position[i] == 'ST'){
    fifa20datasample$position_group[i] == "FORWARD"
  }
}
```

> Error in if (fifa20datasample$team_position[i] == "ST") { :    missing
>   value where TRUE/FALSE needed

```
for(i in 1:length(fifa20datasample$team_position)){
      if(fifa20datasample$team_position[i] == "ST"){
        fifa20datasample$position_group[i] == "FORWARD"
      }
}
```

> Error in if (fifa20datasample$team_position[i] == "ST") { :    missing
>   value where TRUE/FALSE needed

```
for(i in 1:length(fifa20datasample$team_position)){
  if(class(fifa20datasample$team_position[i]) == 'ST'){
    fifa20datasample$position_group[i] == "FORWARD"
  }
}
```

> This does not do anything and does not print an error

```
for(i in 1:length(fifa20datasample$team_position)){
  if(class(fifa20datasample$team_position[i]) == "ST"){
    fifa20datasample$position_group[i] == "FORWARD"
  }
}
```

> This does not do anything and does not print an error

## Edit: I also tried the below for each of the above options

```
for(i in 1:length(fifa20datasample$team_position)){  
     if(fifa20datasample$team_position[i] == 'ST'){
     fifa20datasample$position_group[i] <- "FORWARD"   
      } 
 }
```

Comment: `==` is not for assignment a value to a variable. Have you tried with `fifa20datasample$position_group[i] <- "FORWARD"`

Comment: Yes, I have tried that too and it did not work

Comment: try with `for(i in 1:nrow(fifa20datasample))`. what is `length(fifa20datasample$team_position)` returning?

Comment: Using nrow produces an error argument of length 0. When I ran length(fifa20datasample$team_position) it returned 100

Comment: you should add some rows of you data to the question.

Comment: I have now added some more. There is over 18000 so I am just using a few

Answer (score 1, accepted):

case_when from the dplyr library would be really helpful in this case. It abstracts away alot of the iteration issues that you're seeing.

The sample you've given only has one player and one position, I've included some more options in my example so that you can see how you can really easily cover every other position.

case_when works by going through the data frame and letting you check a condition against a column and amending a column in the same row based on that condition.

https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

fifa20datasample <- tibble(
        short_name = 'J. Obika', 
        team_position = 'ST', 
        position_group = NA
)


fifa20datasample %>% 
        mutate(
                position_group = case_when(
                        team_position %in% c('ST', 'LW') ~  'FORWARD', 
                        team_position %in% c('CAM', 'CM') ~  'MIDFIELD', 
                        team_position %in% c('CB') ~  'DEFENDER', 
                        team_position %in% c('GK') ~  'GOALKEEPER'
                )
        )


  short_name team_position position_group
  <chr>      <chr>         <chr>         
1 J. Obika   ST            FORWARD
```